# When H5+android native development uses leaflet, custom html elements appear and become blank when moving the map

Tags: html

my app is H5+android native development, the MUI used by the ui framework, recently encountered a very strange problem, forgive me for not finding the key to the problem, the problem is this I added some square buttons on the leaflet map , click the button to call the side-sliding menu of mui and display some initially loaded maps and wms services as a list to control the display and hiding of layers, but I found that when I moved the map to different positions, mui popped up Sometimes the layer control is normal, sometimes all become blank, which makes me very confused. I tried to upgrade the leaflet, replace the ui framework, and delete all other style files, but it didn’t solve the problem. I will remove the main code and post it below.

```
/*In this method, I collect the created layer*/
function createLayer(layerConfig) {
  var layer = null;
  var layerType = layerConfig.type;
  map.createPane(layerConfig.id);
  if (layerType == Constants.LAYER_TYPE_TIANDITU_WMTS) {
    layer = L.tileLayer.TianDiTuWMTS(serverUrl + layerConfig.URL, {
      pane: layerConfig.id,
      detectRetina: true,
      identifier: layerConfig.srcLayerId == 0 ? "" : layerConfig.srcLayerId,
    });
    existRetinaLayer = true;
  } else (layerType == Constants.LAYER_TYPE_WMS) {
    layer = L.WMS.source(serverUrl + layerConfig.URL, {
      pane: layerConfig.id,
      transparent: true,
      tiled: true,
      identify: false,
      detectRetina: true,
      format: "image/png",
    }).getLayer(layerConfig.srcLayerId);
  } 
  var layerObject = getLayerById(layerConfig.id);
  if (layerObject) {
    layerObject.layer = layer;
  }
  return layer;
}

/*Then I loop through the levels*/
  mui.each(_allLayers, function (i, e) {
    var _layer = createLayer(e);
    if (_layer) {
      _layer.setZIndex && _layer.setZIndex(i+1);
    }
  });
```

After that, I added these layer data to the map, and also added it to the side menu of mui

The result is shown below
As I continue to adjust and move the map, the following three situations occur respectively

this is normal[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwyrY.jpg)

The following is not normal
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKtO7.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wkiC.png)

And I found that removing three layers will hardly cause this situation, but I verified later that even if I only added 4 layers, I still have to close one to be almost normal.

There will be no problem if you keep switching the sidebar in a normal place, and it will always have a problem in a bad place. I doubt it has something to do with the map. Add: This sidebar only loads dynamically for the first time. Data, the latter is just to control the display and hiding, and when it is not displayed, the data is also in it, but it is blocked by blank space

I hope you guys can give me advice to get me out of this problem

I have tried to delete all the styles except leaflet.css and mui.css, tried to upgrade leaflet to 2.0+, tried not to load Tiantu, tried to use leaflet to open and expand the sidebar, tried to replace mui is vant, I tried to increase the z-index of the sidebar, but there is no way to solve it, I hope that when moving the map, it will no longer affect the data display problem of the sidebar